# How do you programmatically create a new MemberType in Umbraco with the new API

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to create a new member type in Umbraco, which will automatically be created if it doesn't yet exist. However the only code I can find to make a new `MemberType` is marked as Obsolete.

```
umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.MemberType.MakeNew(admin, memberType.Name)
```

How can I do this using the new API? I believe the new API is found under the namespace `Umbraco.Core.Models`.

For reference the [current documentation for v6+ is here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Management-v6/Models/) but is a bit lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Ran across this issue as well. I have numerous users that are separated by company, and the client wants to be able to "un"approve / delete multiple users at once by the group. If I create a `MemberGroup` for each company, then selecting them is easy, as they'll be pre-sorted by the drop down on the Member page in the backend.

I was on to something, as if you look at a current `Member`'s properties, it's actually a `DocumentType`. Therefore, when using the `Services.ContentTypeService` I tried creating a new `ContentType`, which in Umbraco 7 is a `DocumentType`. But you need a `ParentId` to create this.

I didn't know the `ParentId`, so I attempted to extract this by getting a current member in the group `Member`, and getting the `ParentId` that way. However, the ID was `-1`.

If anyone comes across a solution for creating `MemberGroups`, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using umbraco 7 it is best to user the member type service. Below is a simple approach you could employ to achieve this.

```
public void CreateMemberType(IContentTypeComposition parent, string memberTypeAlias)
{
        IMemberType memberType = new Umbraco.Core.Models.MemberType(parent, memberTypeAlias);
        ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberTypeService.Save(memberType);
}
```

To add a member group

```
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.AddRole("Group Name");
```